# Custom REST API for fetch all product with stock information

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, out-of-stock

I am creating custom rest API for getting all products including out of stock products too but I am not able to get out of stock products.

```
/**
 * Get products with filter.
 * 
 * @param string $fieldName
 * @param string $fieldValue
 * @param string $filterType
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface[]
 */
public function getFeedarmy(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria) {
    $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $storesCollection = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
    $storeIds = [];
    foreach ($storesCollection as $sc) {
        $storeIds[] = $sc['store_id'];
    }

    $items = [];
    $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();

    $productCollection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false);
    $productCollection->setFlag('require_stock_items', false);

    //$productCollection->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);

    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setStoreId($storeIds)
            //->joinField( 'manage_stock', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'manage_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left' )
            //->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addCategoryIds()
            //->addTierPriceData()
            ->addPriceData()
            //->addMediaGalleryData()
            ->joinField('inventory_in_stock', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', '*', 'product_ids=entity_id', 'qty>=0', 'left')
            //->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('in' => ['0','1']))
            ->addTaxPercents();

    $this->collectionModifier->apply($productCollection);

    foreach ($searchCriteria->getFilterGroups() as $filterGroups) {
        foreach ($filterGroups->getFilters() as $filter) {
            $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($filter->getField(), [$filter->getConditionType() => $filter->getValue()]);
        }
    }

    if (is_array($searchCriteria->getSortOrders()) && count($searchCriteria->getSortOrders())) {
        foreach ($searchCriteria->getSortOrders() as $sortOrder) {
            $productCollection->addOrder($sortOrder->getField(), $sortOrder->getDirection() == \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder::SORT_ASC ? 'ASC' : 'DESC');
        }
    }

    $productCollection->setPageSize($searchCriteria->getPageSize());
    $productCollection->setCurPage($searchCriteria->getCurrentPage());

    foreach ($productCollection as $item) {

        $customOptions = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($item);
        $data = $item->getData();

        $productCustomOptions = [];
        foreach ($customOptions as $k => $co) {
            $coData = $co->getData();
            $optionValues = [];
            foreach ($co->getValues() as $cov) {
                $optionValues[] = $cov->getData();
            }
            $productCustomOptions[] = array(
                'option_id' => $coData['option_id'],
                'product_id' => $coData['product_id'],
                'type' => $coData['type'],
                'is_require' => $coData['is_require'],
                'sku' => $coData['sku'],
                'max_characters' => $coData['max_characters'],
                'file_extension' => $coData['file_extension'],
                'image_size_x' => $coData['image_size_x'],
                'image_size_y' => $coData['image_size_y'],
                'sort_order' => $coData['sort_order'],
                'default_title' => $coData['default_title'],
                'store_title' => $coData['store_title'],
                'title' => $coData['title'],
                'default_price' => $coData['default_price'],
                'default_price_type' => $coData['default_price_type'],
                'store_price' => $coData['store_price'],
                'store_price_type' => $coData['store_price_type'],
                'price' => $coData['price'],
                'price_type' => $coData['price_type'],
                'values' => $optionValues,
            );
        }

        $items[$item->getId()] = array(
            'id' => $item->getId(),
            'sku' => $data['sku'],
            'name' => $item->getName(),
            'url_key' => $item->getUrlKey(),
            'attribute_set_id' => $item->getAttributeSetId(),
            'store_ids' => $item->getStoreIds(),
            'parent_ids' => $this->_catalogProductTypeConfigurable->getParentIdsByChild($item->getId()),
            'price' => $data['price'],
            'status' => $data['status'],
            'visibility' => $data['visibility'],
            'type_id' => $data['type_id'],
            'created_at' => $data['created_at'],
            'updated_at' => $data['updated_at'],
            'weight' => $data['weight'],
            'weight_unit' => $this->getWeightUnit(),
            'product_links' => $item->getProductLinks(),
            'tier_prices' => $item->getTierPrices(),
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                array(
                    'attribute_code' => 'description',
                    'value' => $item->getDescription()
                ),
                array(
                    'attribute_code' => 'image',
                    'value' => $item->getImage()
                ),
                array(
                    'attribute_code' => 'small_image',
                    'value' => $item->getSmallImage()
                ),
                array(
                    'attribute_code' => 'thumbnail',
                    'value' => $item->getThumbnail()
                ),
                array(
                    'attribute_code' => 'color',
                    'value' => $item->getColor()
                ),
                array(
                    'attribute_code' => 'category_ids',
                    'value' => $item->getCategoryIds()
                ),
            ),
            'stock_information' => array(
                'item_id' => $data['item_id'],
                'product_id' => $data['product_id'],
                'stock_id' => $data['stock_id'],
                'qty' => $data['qty'],
                'is_in_stock' => $data['is_in_stock'],
                'is_qty_decimal' => $data['is_qty_decimal'],
                'use_config_min_qty' => $data['use_config_min_qty'],
                'min_qty' => $data['min_qty'],
                'use_config_min_sale_qty' => $data['use_config_min_sale_qty'],
                'min_sale_qty' => $data['min_sale_qty'],
                'use_config_max_sale_qty' => $data['use_config_max_sale_qty'],
                'max_sale_qty' => $data['max_sale_qty'],
                'use_config_backorders' => $data['use_config_backorders'],
                'backorders' => $data['backorders'],
                'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => $data['use_config_notify_stock_qty'],
                'notify_stock_qty' => $data['notify_stock_qty'],
                'use_config_qty_increments' => $data['use_config_qty_increments'],
                'qty_increments' => $data['qty_increments'],
                'use_config_enable_qty_inc' => $data['use_config_enable_qty_inc'],
                'enable_qty_increments' => $data['enable_qty_increments'],
                'use_config_manage_stock' => $data['use_config_manage_stock'],
                'manage_stock' => $data['manage_stock'],
                'low_stock_date' => $data['low_stock_date'],
                'is_decimal_divided' => $data['is_decimal_divided'],
                'stock_status_changed_auto' => $data['stock_status_changed_auto'],
            ),
            'custom_options' => $productCustomOptions,
        );

        //$items[$item->getId()] = $item;
    }

    $searchResult = $this->searchResultFactory->create();

    $searchResult->setItems($items);


    $searchResult->setTotalCount(count($items));
    $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);

    return $searchResult;
}
```

I tried to identify the reason and found that the query for getting the product has joined with `kdmcatalog_product_entity` and `kdmcatalog_product_index_price`, where if the product is out of stock removed from the `kdmcatalog_product_index_price` table so the join does not return the out of stock of products

```
SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) 
AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `at_inventory_in_stock`.* 
FROM `kdmcatalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN
`kdmcatalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 
LEFT JOIN `kdmcataloginventory_stock_item` 
AS `at_inventory_in_stock` ON (at_inventory_in_stock.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (qty>=0) 
WHERE (`e`.`sku` = 'ab,Nike Air Max Dia SE-us 5.5')
```

Comment: Have you got solution for get product with stock information in rest API. I am facing for same issue.

Answer (score 0):

this module will solve your issue,
it will return the stockinfo in searchCriteria.
https://github.com/menacoders/Stock-Info-API-searchCriteria